# Setting specific thresholds for a repeated singlestat in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I am a Singlestat Panel that is repeated based on one of the variables set on the dashboard. Is there any proper way to set individual thresholds for some of the panels and not replicate it across all the repeated panels? Or the only was is just by replicating manually the Singlestat?

Answer (score 0):

The point of [repeating panels](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/reference/templating/#repeating-panels) is to define the template only once and apply it on all values of the variable. This is consistent with having a panel representing a measure.

If the values represent identified measures, you'd better duplicate the panels. If you still need some templating for that, you can use an external templating system to generate the dashboard and upload them.